# c++ coverting user input double into string with decimal

Tags: c++, string, double

Hi guys i am trying to convert user input double into string and concatenate with other string, however the double doesn't include the .00 at the back. For example if i enter 72.98 it print out 72.98 correctly but when i enter 72.00 it only print out 72 without the .00. How can i make sure the .00 is there.

```
string desc, date;
double amount;
. 
.
.   
cout << "Enter expenses amount: ";
cin >> amount;
//print to see the amount
cout << amount << endl;
.
.
.
string amt;
amt = static_cast<ostringstream*>( &(ostringstream() << amount) )->str();

string input = desc + ":" + amt + ":" + date;
```

I have tried below code but is not working as well, it give some funny numbers

```
stringstream amtstr;
amtstr << setprecision(2) << fixed << amount;
cout << amtstr << endl;;
```

Comment: Define "funny numbers". Seems to [work for me](http://rextester.com/ERU96086)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik If you had copied the exact code, you would have seen [the problem](http://ideone.com/uYvBVk) ;)

Comment: This should work `std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << amount << endl;`

Comment: @PureProgrammer But he wants to put it into a string (please see the title), not print it. The print at the end is just to make the result visible.

Comment: @leemes Sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

Your stringstream approach works. You simply don't print its content when you write

```
cout << amtstr << endl;
```

Instead, this code prints **the stringsteam object itself**. This is defined to print the **address** off the object, rather than the string content.

You can access the string content using the `str()` member function, like:

```
cout << amtstr.str() << endl;
```

See this [**live demo**](http://ideone.com/WZ7bTC).

Comment: i tried putting .str() and it didnt now print any number, just a blank line

Answer (score 0):

Does your compiler support [std::to_string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/)?

```
auto input = std::to_string(myDouble);
if (input.find(".") == std::string::npos) {
    input += ".00";
}
else {
    input = input.substr(0, input.find(".") + 3);
}
```

Comment: I don't see how. This would still produce `72.1`, not `72.10`, as far as I can tell.

Comment: When I run it, it prints 72.10 (Visual Studio 2013)

Comment: Sorry doesnt work for me i have include <string> and it still give me error for to_string

Comment: What is your compiler?

Comment: @TommyYap If you're using GCC, it is a known bug (something related to wrong #defines).

Answer (score 0):

You could use good old C-style formatting.

```
char szBuffer[64];
sprintf(szBuffer, "%.2f", amount);
std::string amt = szBuffer;
```

Comment: Posting a C solution to a C++ question (even if the code is C++-compatible) is not so good. Despite this fact, you're producing a buffer overflow for large numbers. See http://ideone.com/JucFmH